# why gmdate($date) return different value vs DateTimeZone('GMT') and setTimestamp()?

Tags: php, datetime

exist some difference into function `gmdate()` and `DateTimeZone('GMT')` ?

yes I can't get the correct value `1035406623` using the class DateTime:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


$f = '2002-10-23T15:57:03Z';
$TS = strtotime($f);


$Q1 = new DateTime($f, new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
print_r($Q1 -> getTimestamp());
echo '<hr />';


$Q2 = new DateTime();
$Q2 -> setTimestamp($TS);
print_r($Q2 -> getTimestamp());
echo '<hr />';


// I only can "recovery" the correct date CORRECT timestamp,
// REAL and correct UTC time taked from $f/$TS using this obtuse line:
echo mktime(gmdate('H', $TS), gmdate('i', $TS), gmdate('s', $TS), gmdate('m', $TS), gmdate('d', $TS), gmdate('Y', $TS));
```

How I can get the value correct (`1035406623`) using DateTime with servers in... any country!?

Comment: 1035406623 is not the correct timestamp. I get 1035388623.

Comment: you can confirm from TWO ways: `echo mktime(gmdate('H', $TS), gmdate('i', $TS), gmdate('s', $TS), gmdate('m', $TS), gmdate('d', $TS), gmdate('Y', $TS));` and also you can confirm from MySQL: `QUERY("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$f')") -> FETCH_OBJECT();` why `DateTime` can´t return the value correct?

Comment: I don't know where the wrong timestamp comes from. It does not reproduce your date 2002-10-23T15: 57: 03Z. echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s',1035406623); -> 2002-10-23 20:57:03

Comment: Master @jspit logically do: `echo mktime(gmdate('H', $TS), gmdate('i', $TS), gmdate('s', $TS), gmdate('m', $TS), gmdate('d', $TS), gmdate('Y', $TS));` is a bad solution and MySQL work fine, but the target is doit using PHP, no't SQL or JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

mktime requires a local time for the arguments. However, you use utc times. The [gmmktime](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.gmmktime.php) function receives utc times.
This is the function that gives you the right timestamp.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    
$f = '2002-10-23T15:57:03Z';  //Z -> UTC-Time
$ts = strtotime($f);
echo $ts."<br>\n";
        
echo gmmktime(gmdate('H', $ts), gmdate('i', $ts), gmdate('s', $ts), gmdate('m', $ts), gmdate('d', $ts), gmdate('Y', $ts));
```

Output:

```
1035388623
1035388623
```

The default time zone can be commented out or changed for testing. The results stay the same.

Comment: yes, `gmmktime` use UTC by default, my Q is how is possible get the CORRECT value: `1035406623` from Date()   Time PHP ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't offer you a PHP solution that delivers wrong desired values!

Comment: thanks master @jspit, the correct TIMESTAMP in UTC of `2002-10-23T15:57:03Z` is `1035406623`, you can confirm running: `QUERY("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2002-10-23T15:57:03Z')") -> FETCH_OBJECT();` why DateTime from PHP can't return this value however `gmdate` from PHP yes can?

Comment: Your MySQL query is wrong and therefore provides a wrong timestamp! The MySQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP function ignores the Z at the end and interprets the date with the system time zone and not as UTC. Workaround: SET @@session.time_zone = "+00:00";
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2002-10-23T15:57:03Z')

Comment: Many thanks master @jspit with your help now ALL is clear for me: https://pastebin.com/YMaDYFyV this lines (your code) have the answer :-)